# Radius of convergence using ratio test complex

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have tried to compute the radius of convergence for the following series: $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}ni^nz^n$$
but I keep getting $zi$ as the limit when I take the ratio.

What is the correct method for this problem?

Comment: You need to look at the absolute value of the quotients.

Comment: So then notice that $|zi| = |z| < 1$ if and only if.....

Comment: iff it converges, okay got it, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cauchy Hadamard formula:

$$\frac1R=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|ni^n|}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n\,|i|=1\implies R=1$$